# Google Analytics Custom Variables Not Being Recorded

Tags: google-analytics

For some reason my custom variables are not showing up in my Google Analytics reports (Visitors > Custom Variables > "There is no data for this view") even after 24 hours.

Anybody see what I'm missing?

I downloaded the [Google Analytics Debugger (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) Chrome Extension and got the following report.

```
_gaq.push processing : "[_setAccount,UA-example-1]"
ga_debug.js:21_gaq.push processing : "[_setCustomVar,1,ismale,True,3]"
ga_debug.js:21_gaq.push processing : "[_setCustomVar,2,ispremium,False,3]"
ga_debug.js:21_gaq.push processing : "[_setCustomVar,3,universityid,1,3]"
ga_debug.js:21_gaq.push processing : "[_setCustomVar,4,age,24,3]"
ga_debug.js:21_gaq.push processing : "[_setCustomVar,5,monthsregistered,5,3]"
ga_debug.js:21_gaq.push processing : "[_trackPageview]"
ga_debug.js:21Track Pageview
ga_debug.js:21Tracking beacon sent!

utmwv=5.1.6d&utms=19&utmn=112552813&utmhn=example.com&utme=8(ismale*ispremium*universityid*age*monthsregistered)9(True*False*1*24*5)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1920x1080&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=11.0%20r1&utmdt=example&utmhid=637350171&utmr=-&utmp=%2F&utmac=UA-example-1&utmcc=__utma%3D243787922.1113545762.1320772787.1320798586.1320828138.3%3B%2B__utmz%3D243787922.1320772787.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=qQ~

ga_debug.js:21
Account ID               : UA-example-1
Page Title               : example
Host Name                : example.com
Page                     : /
Referring URL            : -
Hit ID                   : 637350171
Visitor ID               : 1113545762
Session Count            : 3
Session Time - First     : Tue Nov 08 2011 12:19:47 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Session Time - Last      : Tue Nov 08 2011 19:29:46 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Session Time - Current   : Wed Nov 09 2011 03:42:18 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Campaign Time            : Tue Nov 08 2011 12:19:47 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : (direct)
Campaign Medium          : (none);
Campaign Name            : (direct)
Custom Var 1             : label:'ismale' value:'True' scope:'Page'
Custom Var 2             : label:'ispremium' value:'False' scope:'Page'
Custom Var 3             : label:'universityid' value:'1' scope:'Page'
Custom Var 4             : label:'age' value:'24' scope:'Page'
Custom Var 5             : label:'monthsregistered' value:'5' scope:'Page'
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 11.0 r1
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1920x1080
Color Depth              : 32-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.1.6d
Cachebuster              : 112552813
```

Comment: Assuming these pageviews are going to the account you're intending them to, your custom variable data should eventually appear. They can be a little slow to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, apparently it takes a little longer for Custom Variables to show up in the reports. Thanks @yahelc

Comment: How much did it take? I'm currently waiting for the data to appear.

Comment: may take up to 2 days, as long as you can see it in the console with the debugger you should be good (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)